# Highest index to dropped item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dropable board.

To make it droppable i use.

```
$("#board").droppable
({  
    greedy: true,
    tolerance:"pointer",
    drop: function (event, ui) 
    {
        .resizable
        ({containment:'#bord',aspectRatio: true})
        .css({position: 'absolute'})
        var index_highest = 0;
        $('.sleep').each(function()
        {
         var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
         if(index_current > index_highest) 
         {
          index_highest = index_current;
         } 
        }) 
          .css('z-index',index_highest);            
    }
});
```

My problem is that if i drop something, everything i have dropped gets the highest index so not only the last dropped item.

I also tryd

```
 $(this).css('z-index',index_highest);
```

But it isnt working, I get the highest z-index so that isn't the problem.

The dropped items use the class sleep.

How can i set the z-index only to the last dropped item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this on drop event wich is working for me .

```
drop: function (event, ui) 
    {
        var index_highest = 0;
        $('.sleep').each(function()
        {
          var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
          if(index_current > index_highest) 
          {
            index_highest = index_current;
          }

        }) 
            .css('z-index',index_highest);

    }
```